# How to loop over JButtonGroup using .hasMoreElements()?

Tags: java, swing, loops, enums

So as the title suggests, it's a pretty simple question, though for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I've got:

```
while(styleButtonGroup.getElements().hasMoreElements()){
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
    }
```

However, the problem is that my program doesn't seem to be looping through the buttons - instead it's simply trying to add the first button over and over again. For example, if I run the following, I should get a null pointer exception on the 3rd call of .nextElement() (since this button group only has 2 buttons...), though there is no error and I keep getting the output "True 2"...

```
while(styleButtonGroup.getElements().hasMoreElements()){
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(styleButtonGroup.getElements().nextElement());
        System.out.println(styleButtonGroup.getElements().hasMoreElements() + " " + styleButtonGroup.getButtonCount());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one instance of your `Enumerator`, instead of constantly creating a new one

```
Enumeration<Component> elements = styleButtonGroup.getElements();
while(elements.hasMoreElements()){
        mainPanel.add(elements.nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(elements.nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(elements.nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(elements.nextElement());
        mainPanel.add(elements.nextElement());
        System.out.println(elements.hasMoreElements() + " " + styleButtonGroup.getButtonCount());
    }
```

Comment: Yep, perfect thanks :) At least I'll be able to complete this assignment now haha

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a fresh `Enumeration` each time you call `styleButtonGroup.getElements()`, and each fresh enumeration starts from the beginning of the group.

You probably want something like:

```
Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = styleButtonGroup.getElements();
while (buttons.hasMoreElements()) {
    mainPanel.add(buttons.nextElement());
}
```

Comment: Yep, perfect thanks :) At least I'll be able to complete this assignment now haha